# is there any reference you consider a basic ajax reference to create a popup menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lightbox

i would like know some reference. I know i can googling it. but prefer from your point of view and your understanding what is the basic one...thanks ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean context menu, but if you do I've used the jQuery Context Menu Plugin a few times and found it very easy to tweak.  There is a demo on their website so you can see it live in action.

[jQuery Context Menu Plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/#demo)